# If $T :R^7\to R^7$ be a linear transformation such that $T^2(x)=0$ what is the nullity of T?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T :R^7\to R^7$ be a linear transformation such that

$T^2(x)=0$

what is the  nullity of T?

Answer (score 3):

If $T^2(x)=0$ for all $x \in R^7$, then $\text{im }T \subseteq \ker T$, so that $\text{rank } T \leq \dim \ker T$, so that by the rank/nullity-theorem, we have $$  2 \dim \ker T\leq \text{rank } T + \dim \ker T = 7$$

This implies that the nullity is three or less, that is, either $0,1,2,3$. As Ross Millikan writes in his answer, you should be able to find matrices with nullity each of these numbers.

Comment: The nullity of $T$ doesn't have to be that large.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thank you! I was too quick - I have revised the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To have $T^2=0$ we must have Image$(T) \subseteq $ Kernel$(T)$.  This shows $0 \le $ Rank$(T) \le 3, 7 \ge $ Nullity$(T) \ge 4$.  You should be able to find examples at each end of the range.